# A direct formula for counting 1s in binary form of a positive integer

Tags: number-theory, binary, binary-operations

*The question is edited based on the @Damien comment.*

**Question:**

*Is there a  direct formula (not  recursive) for counting 1s in binary form of a positive integer?*

For example, suppose the formula is called $f(n)$ for a positive integer $n$. Then, we have

$f(3)=2$, $f(13)=3$ and $f(16)=1$, since we have $[3]_2=11$,$[13]_2=1101$ and $[16]_2=10000$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120) in OEIS.

Comment: @lulu It is a sequence and not a formula. Am I right?

Comment: Which type of formula do you want? For example $f(n) = f(n/2) + n  \mod 2$ and $f(0)=0$

Comment: From the discussion and references attached to that OEIS link, you can get a sense of what is known about computing it.  No simple closed formula, for instance, but it does have nice "self replicating" properties which are discussed.

Comment: @Damien A direct formula. The $f(n) = f(n/2) + n  \mod 2$ is a recursive one. Thunks

Comment: @user0410 You should put this kind of information in the post

Comment: @lulu You are right. Thanks for the proposed link.

Comment: @Damien Based on your suggestion, the question will be edited. Thanks

Comment: This question has already been asked: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3325992/573047).